# When $\rho$ is 0 mvncdf gives an error

Tags: matlab, distribution

I am trying to find the cdf of a bivariate normal distribution. I am using the mvncdf function to calculate the cdf of a bivariate normal distribution.

Bivariate normal distribution:[image]

When $\rho$ is 0,mvncdf in matlab gives an error.

It says SIGMA must be a square, symmetric, positive definite matrix.

I know when $\rho$ is 0, the distribution reduces to a simpler one, but how do I implement this? Is it using normcdf?

How do I solve this problem?

Based on this image,[image]

I just need to generate two cdfs and multiply it together right?

This is what I am doing now:

```
term1 = normcdf(-norminv(K1/(1-R)),0,1)*normcdf(C,0,1);
term2 = normcdf(-norminv(K2/(1-R)),0,1)*normcdf(C,0,1);
```

Code for cov matrix:

```
a=sqrt(rho);
cov_mat = [1 -sqrt(1-a^2);-sqrt(1-a^2) 1];
term1 = mvncdf([-norminv(K1/(1-R)) C], [0 0], cov_mat);
term2 = mvncdf([-norminv(K2/(1-R)) C], [0 0], cov_mat);
```

Comment: What is your code? How do you use rho to build the covariance matrix sigma?

Comment: But there are undefined variables. I can't run your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the correlation is zero, just generate the results for the two independent normals.

What you've written is the density, not the CDF.  For normals, there is no closed-form formula for the CDF.  However, the joint CDF P{X<sub>1</sub> <= x<sub>1</sub> & X<sub>2</sub> <= x<sub>2</sub>} = P{X<sub>1</sub> <= x<sub>1</sub>} * P{X<sub>2</sub> <= x<sub>2</sub>} when they're independent, and Matlab can certainly evaluate the results on the right-hand side.

Comment: Then need to multiply the two independent normals to get the cdf right? like I have put in the question?

Comment: he joint CDF P{X1 <= x1 & X2 <= x2} = P{X1 <= x1} * P{X2 <= x2}  = normcdf(x1,0,1)*normcdf(x2,0,1)?

Comment: Not being a Matlab user, I don't know the specific function calls. If those are normal CDF evaluations with first argument being the normal value, second being mean, and third being standard deviation or variance, then that should be correct as long as you plug in the appropriate values for your particular problem.

Comment: Product of two independent cdf's, yes.